# Select negative values and positive from a table with varchar data type in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have table in SQL Server which contains a column of type `VARCHAR`.

The column can contain whole values (like 20.00) as well as fraction values (like 20.50).

I want to display whole values (like 20.00) and fraction values (like 20.50) in different columns using a SQL query.

Output should like

```
A         B
--------------
20.00    20.50
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! So why on earth are you storing *numerical* values in a `varchar` ?!?!? Use the appropriate datatype - probably `decimal(p,s)` here!

Comment: Title says *negative* and *positive* values, but in the question you're asking about whole and fractional values.... please try to be **consistent**! What are you asking about now?

Answer (score 0):

As marc commented better not to use `VARCHAR` for a number but if you just want to get the answer try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #test_table(sal VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #test_table(sal) VALUES('20.00'), ('20.50'), ('20.04'), ('30.00')

SELECT  CASE WHEN RIGHT(sal, 2) = '00' THEN sal END AS A
        ,CASE WHEN RIGHT(sal, 2) != '00' THEN sal END AS B
FROM #test_table
```